# NSTimer doesn't work without UIApplication?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, uiapplication, cfrunloop

I have a custom iPhone application which doesn't rely on UIKit in any way (it is not linked to UIKit). This means that I'm not using **UIApplication** and therefore not calling **UIApplicationMain**.

The problem is that when I create a timer it never fires. The timer is created like that:

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
```

I am suspecting that the problem might be run-loop related as after I finish basic initialization in "**main()**" , I do this:

```
NSLog(@"Starting application ...");
applicationInstance = [MyApp alloc];
[applicationInstance setMainLayer:mainLayer];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(runApplication) toTarget:applicationInstance withObject:nil];

CFRunLoopRun();
```

I reverse-engineered UIKit and noticed that UIApplication does much more things like registering for system events etc. **NSTimer** might be relying on one of those things. The other thing I've noticed is that in UIApplication's delegate the thread is the same as in main().

How do I get **NSTimer** to work properly? If it is run-loop related, can someone point out the error? "**CFRunLoopRun()**" is used to hang up the main thread so the rest of the application can run. I don't think it is right though.

Edit: I think the run loop needs to be configred. Somehow ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is definitely run loop-related; see the [NSTimer reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), specifically, the introduction:

> Timers work in conjunction with run loops. To use a timer effectively, you should be aware of how run loops operate—see [`NSRunLoop`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunLoop) and [*Threading Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i). Note in particular that run loops retain their timers, so you can release a timer after you have added it to a run loop.

Comment: Did you check out the Threaded Programming Guide? The section on "Using Run Loops"? I haven't created my own Run Loop before, but that seems to me to be a good place to start!

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't provide any info :(

Comment: "Listing 3-1  Creating a run loop observer" is exactly what you're trying to do -- create a run loop and add an NSTimer -- is it not?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was pretty simple

```
NSTimer * timeUpdateTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE]; 
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timeUpdateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Thanks for the tip **Shaggy Frog**